# How to output groups with *ngFor in angular based on property?

Tags: angular

Assume I have the following object 'myarr':

```
[
    {'name':'Mary', 'chapter':'Chapter 1'},
    {'name':'Joseph', 'chapter':'Chapter 1'},
    {'name':'John', 'chapter':'Chapter 2'},
    {'name':'Carl', 'chapter':'Chapter 3'},
    {'name':'Jacob', 'chapter':'Chapter 3'}
]
```

Is it possible to make it so that I can output the following:

**Chapter 1**

Mary

Joseph

**Chapter 2**

John

**Chapter 3**

Carl

Jacob

If so, what is a good way to accomplish this with just one list? I don't want to hardcode Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Chapter 3. I would like to infer from the data.

```html
<div *ngFor="let name of myarr">
    // two ngFor to get the chapter?
    {{name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need additional processing for the list. basically grouping records by chapter.

Comment: you can achive this with a pipe filter... Although it is kind of tricky I guess

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh I would prefer not to because I want to make the each list item editable inline, sortable, filterable, and ngModel does not play nice when you do all the grouping, etc. That is why I prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @Rolando I can understand that. There is another "hack" you can do. You can introduce index variable in ngFor loop `let index = $index'. Sort array by chapter and them compare current item.chapter with item[index-1].chapter. If those don't match, you know that you need to render chapter header. But that's "dirty" code. I can try to follow up with stackblitz example, don't have time for it now. But sincerely , I would think about that problem differently.

Comment: @Rolando see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

There is one "dirty" hack that you can make in order to achieve it. Personally I recommend you to go with the grouping of items, but here is the 100% working solution in case you want to stick to a single list.

Steps are:

1. Sort your array by chapter
2. Rely on having different chapter for the previous item when rendering header

**TypeScript**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  arr = [
    {'name':'Mary', 'chapter':'Chapter 1'},
    {'name':'Joseph', 'chapter':'Chapter 1'},
    {'name':'John', 'chapter':'Chapter 2'},
    {'name':'Carl', 'chapter':'Chapter 3'},
    {'name':'Jacob', 'chapter':'Chapter 3'}
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.arr = this.arr.sort((a,b) => a.chapter > b.chapter ? 1 : -1);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr; let index = index">
  <h3 *ngIf="!arr[index-1] || item.chapter !== arr[index-1].chapter">{{item.chapter}}</h3>
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4y6anf

Answer (score 1):

Check this example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/group-by-inangular

You need to group your items by chapter first, and that should be done in your ts file like this:

```
groupArr = this.myarr.reduce((r,{group})=>{
        if(!r.some(o=>o.chapter==chapter)){
          r.push({chapter,groupItem:this.myarr.filter(v=>v.chapter==chapter)});
    }
    return r;
    },[]);
```

and then in your html do this:

```
   <table>
     <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
        <tbody *ngFor="let item of groupArr">
           <ng-container>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>{{item.group}}</b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr *ngFor="let value of item.groupItem">
               <td>{{value.name}}</td>
             </tr>
           </ng-container>
         </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a function to determine whether to display the chapter. Using a trackBy function in the ngFor will help performance.

component:

```
  lastChapter = '';
  myarr = [
    {'name':'Mary', 'chapter':'Chapter 1'},
    {'name':'Joseph', 'chapter':'Chapter 1'},
    {'name':'John', 'chapter':'Chapter 2'},
    {'name':'Carl', 'chapter':'Chapter 3'},
    {'name':'Jacob', 'chapter':'Chapter 3'}
  ];

  displayChapter(item): boolean {
    if (item.chapter !== this.lastChapter) {
      this.lastChapter = item.chapter;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  trackChapter(index: number; item: any): string {
    return item.name + item.chapter;
  }
```

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myarr; trackBy: trackChapter">
  <h1 *ngIf="displayChapter(item)">{{ item.chapter }}</h1>
  <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3lpali)

Comment: This is a bad idea. adding functions in templates will cause the continuous reevaluation of the function

Comment: It's not taboo to use functions in the template, you just need to use it sparingly. If you use a trackBy here it will drastically reduce reevaluations