# Angular Categorize and display title for list of items in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor

I have an array of objects:

```
[{name: "Mary", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1992},
{name: "Bob", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1994},
{name: "Paul", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1994},
{name: "Christy", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1993},
{name: "John", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1993},
{name: "Kenny", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1993},
}]
```

I am displaying these from the template using *ngFor. But now I need to categorize based on dob (it will be grouped in order as shown) and display them under 1 title.

Ex:

> **Year 1992** Mary
>
> **Year 1994** Bob Paul
>
> **Year 1993** Christy John Kenny

I can achieve this by matching the index value or some other logic in a function. But let's just say we need to handle this only through *ngIf and *ngFor (or any other template changes). Is there a way?

Comment: Why not just use an `orderBy` pipe? Is there a specific need to try and accomplish this just in the html iterated template?

Comment: I am using async pipe to directly display the items on the page. Which means I am subscribing already. In order to make non-template changes, I will need to re-subscribe which calls the API twice in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this solution from another post. Had to only update the HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58923774/4567978

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format the result before binding:

```js
let arr = [{name: "Mary", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1992},
{name: "Bob", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1994},
{name: "Paul", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1994},
{name: "Christy", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1993},
{name: "John", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1993},
{name: "Kenny", "salary": "22k", "category": "A", "dob": 1993},
];

const years = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.dob))];

const result = years.map(year => {
   return {
     year: year,
     names:  (arr.filter(p => p.dob === year  ).map(j => j.name)).join(' ')
   }
})
console.log(result);
```

Once you have formatted data, easily you can bind them, it will create the final list:

```
[
  { "year": 1992, "names": "Mary" },
  { "year": 1994, "names": "Bob Paul" },
  { "year": 1993, "names": "Christy John Kenny" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

as Ali Adravi commented, you can use a `Set` to filter out duplicates from your source array.

In your component code:

```
const sourceArray = [...];
  ...
  const years = [...new Set(sourceArray.map(item => item.dob))];
  const categorizedItems = years.map(year => {
    return {
      year: year,
      names: sourceArray.filter(item => item.dob === year)
    }
  });
  ...
```

Then in your `html` file:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="year">{{item.year}}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let person of item.names">
      <span class="personName">{{person.name}}</span>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Let me know if that helped!